# preg_match in php for select tags

Tags: php, preg-match

I want to get all options value between below select tags using preg_match

```
<select id="current-statement" name="current-statement" data-reactid=".4.2.2.1.0.2.1.1.0">
<option value="current" data-reactid=".4.2.2.1.0.2.1.1.0.0">Current Statement</option>
<option value="90989266-c853-289b-dfea-3cdfe2213db7" data-reactid=".4.2.2.1.0.2.1.1.0.1">1st Statement</option>
<option value="165eb5ea-fd48-53c8-020b-6e3287859922" data-reactid=".4.2.2.1.0.2.1.1.0.2">second statement</option>
<option value="0d558fa0-8f48-afa2-7a9a-e8f85fbbbc42" data-reactid=".4.2.2.1.0.2.1.1.0.3">third statement</option>
<option value="9c78f8aa-3b09-4574-1c10-8f450b45eb5b" data-reactid=".2.0.0.1.0.2.1.1.0.4">4th statement</option>
</select>
```

I am trying to get it like following preg_match but unable to do so

```
preg_match("'<select id=\"current-statement\" name=\"current-statement\" data-reactid=\".4.2.2.1.0.2.1.1.0\">(.*?)</select>'", $content, $match);

if($match) echo "result=".$match[1];
```

Please help

Comment: Why not use DOM? With DOM, this should be rather straight-forward. With regex, you will have to perform at least 2 steps (if you want a readable solution), or one huge regex with `\G` operator and there is no guarantee it will always work.

Answer (score 0):

With DOM, the task is reduced to writing a working XPath expression:

```
//select/*/text()
```

where

- `//select` - find all `select` tags

  - `/*` - then any child inside

    - `/text()` - and fetch the text nodes.

See [PHP demo](https://ideone.com/q8NUXh):

```
$html = <<<DATA
<select id="current-statement" name="current-statement" data-reactid=".4.2.2.1.0.2.1.1.0">
<option value="current" data-reactid=".4.2.2.1.0.2.1.1.0.0">Current Statement</option>
<option value="90989266-c853-289b-dfea-3cdfe2213db7" data-reactid=".4.2.2.1.0.2.1.1.0.1">1st Statement</option>
<option value="165eb5ea-fd48-53c8-020b-6e3287859922" data-reactid=".4.2.2.1.0.2.1.1.0.2">second statement</option>
<option value="0d558fa0-8f48-afa2-7a9a-e8f85fbbbc42" data-reactid=".4.2.2.1.0.2.1.1.0.3">third statement</option>
<option value="9c78f8aa-3b09-4574-1c10-8f450b45eb5b" data-reactid=".2.0.0.1.0.2.1.1.0.4">4th statement</option>
</select>
DATA;

$dom = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');
$dom->loadHTML($html, LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);

$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$opts = $xpath->query('//select/*/text()');
$res = array();
foreach($opts as $opt) { 
   array_push($res, $opt->nodeValue);
}
print_r($res);
```

Comment: FYI, just for educational purposes, see a regex solution: [`preg_match_all('~(?:(?!\A)\G<\/option>(?=[^<]*(?:<(?!\/select)[^<]*)*<\/select>)|<select\b[^<]*?>)\s*<option\b[^<]*?>\K[^<]*~', $s, $matches)`](https://regex101.com/r/Yg5PdI/1). Rather ugly and error prone.